# How to make CircleCI run on every push to GitHub repository?

Tags: git, heroku, github, continuous-integration, circleci

I want to achieve the workflow in my project like that: I make a `git push origin master`, then the tests are run, then after the tests the project is deployed to Heroku.

I've already set up auto deployment on Heroku from github repository and checked that it should wait for the CircleCI tests to pass. But when I run `git push origin master` (where `origin` is the GitHub repository), nothing happens. And the tests are run only when I manually go into the CircleCI dashboard, then to the project's settings, then to `Test commands` and then press the `Save and Go`. This triggers a new build, and after it's finished, my app is deployed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: One method is to use two separate services that exist on GitHub. The GitHub Auto-Deployment will create a deployment event anytime there is a push to `master`. So long as you make changes in a feature branch and only merge to `master` after CircleCI tests, using protected branches/statuses, it will trigger.  Then you can set up a HerokuBeta service that calls Heroku whenever the Deployment event is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a huge stab in the dark here because you didn't link anything but do you have a `circle.yml` file in the root of your repository with all the test and deployment commands that you need? Sounds like you're missing that. After adding that, the workflow you expect should "Just Work".

Comment: I don't have it but I'm not sure if I need it, because if I run my tests manually (as I said in the question), they will pass (that's why I assume that the tests commands are already set up)